# Spread spectrum

Tags: modulation, spread-spectrum

Are Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum (FHSS) and Direct Sequence Spread Sequence (DSSS) modulations? I am confused because I have read that these are also used e.g. with Gaussian Frequency-Shift Keying (GFSK) modulation? Can modulated signal be modulated again?

Comment: FHSS and DSSS refer to the carrier frequency (jumping around in the spectrum) not the modulation used.

Comment: @Jim Dearden What are they technically? I have seen thet they are referred to as modulations.

Answer (score 1):

Edited Answer:

FHSS and DSSS alter the frequency and amplitude of a signal and so are technically modulations but they are not like other modulation schemes because they take place at a different point in the transmission chain, so you can have FHSS with M-QAM but you can't have M-QAM with BPSK for example.

When you transmit data using a M-QAM scheme, you take your bits, convert your bits into symbols and then use your modulation scheme to map those symbols to a waveform and then that waveform then is passed on for transmission.So in other words, in M-QAM for example, you are modulating the carrier signal with the symbol data.With FHSS and DSSS you are modulating the carrier signal but you are modulating it by using a unique user specific code or some other code / pattern so the two modulations are very different.

Comment: So with e.g. FHSS modulation is implemented with different carrier frequencies?

Comment: FHSS modulates the carrier signal by altering the carrier signal's frequency many times over the course of transmission.

Comment: I have edited my very short answer to explain the difference in modulations a bit more.